# How to run a C program and get output of the program using Twisted Python

Tags: python, c, linux, twisted, irc

I have a Python Bot written using Twisted framework and I have a C program that outputs certain text.  How would I be able to run have Twisted run the C program using a command, collect the output, then print the output back to me?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is [getProcessOutput](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.utils.getProcessOutput.html):

```
from twisted.internet.utils import getProcessOutput
df = getProcessOutput('ls', args=('/home','-lah'))
df.addCallback( printOutput )
```

Also see http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html in case you need something more complex.

Comment: A naive question, but why use this over python's subprocess module?